# Bind controls to a stackpanel in winui3

Tags: c#, winui-3

i'm making in a music player program, and now I need to add a page to show the playlist's detail, such as the musics and the music's artists in the playlist.I'm going to make some musics' card and add them to a stackpanel.

I have achieved this by getting this panel object and calling its add function, but can I achieve it through data binding?

This is the way i used before

```
<StackPanel x:Name="PanelMusics" />

PanelMusics.Children.Add(...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `ListView` or `ItemsRepeater` instead of `StackPanel`.

This is a simple example how to use `ListView` with the help of the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction) NuGet package.

**MusicItem.cs**

```cs
namespace MusicCardsSample;

public class MusicItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string Artist { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MusicCardsSample;

// The "CommunityTookit.Mvvm" needs this class to be "partial".
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // The "CommunityTookit.Mvvm" creates 
    // an UI-interactable property "MusicItems" for you.
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<MusicItem> musicItems = new();

    // The "CommunityTookit.Mvvm" creates
    // an "AddMusicItemCommand" command for you.
    [RelayCommand]
    private void AddMusicItem(MusicItem item)
    {
        musicItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace MusicCardsSample;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="MusicCardsSample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:MusicCardsSample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox
                x:Name="TitleTextBlock"
                PlaceholderText="Title" />
            <TextBox
                x:Name="ArtistTextBlock"
                PlaceholderText="Artist" />
            <Button
                Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddMusicItemCommand}"
                Content="Add">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <local:MusicItem
                        Title="{x:Bind TitleTextBlock.Text, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Artist="{x:Bind ArtistTextBlock.Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MusicItems, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MusicItem">
                    <!--You can design your music cards here.-->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock
                            FontSize="9"
                            Text="{x:Bind Artist}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```